# Compile error with sqlite and winrt

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-runtime

I just opened the csharp version of the geolocation sample of the SDK and I would like to do a simple change: I would like that the background task save the coordinates in a sqlite db.

To do this, I added the `Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Package, the SQLite for Windows Runtime, the sqlite-net library via codeplex, and switched the target Platform from any cpu to x64`.

Trying to compile, I receive this error

```
Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Foundation.Point' was found in multiple 
referenced winmd files. Please remove either 'C:\Program Files (x86)\
Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\11.0\References
\CommonConfiguration\neutral\platform.winmd' or 'C:\Program Files (x86)\
Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd' 
from the list of referenced files.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: me too having same problem :(

Comment: Please see this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2738078

Comment: @HeShiming.That fixed it for me. The key sentence is "To work around this issue, remove the Microsoft.VCLibs component in the references of each C# project.". That fixed the compiler error anyway. Later I ran into other problems, which may or not be related, so I cannot confirm that it really fixes the issue. (I just gave up on SQLite for WinRT 8.1. I was using VS2013)

Answer (score 4):

I have heard that if you move all the SQLite code to a Windows store class library and referencing it from the background task will get rid of the problem.

my workaround is just to remove/rename 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd' its only 18kb so I think its unlikely that ill need anything in there

Comment: When I remove the C++ runtime reference from the project ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2738078 ) and clean and build, I am able to get rid of this  "Windows.Foundation.Point was found in multiple  referenced winmd files" error but when I add the sqlite-net nuget package to the project, I get a lot of type errors as the wrapper depends on the removed c++ reference. However, When I created a Windows 8.1 Class library project, added SQLite and C++ references and added Sqlite-net nuget and set the target platform to 64, builds without any errors.